# Vim matchadd command does not work with multiple tabs

Tags: vim, tabs, highlight

These are the line used in order to set the custom word highlight in the `.vimrc` file.

```
hi CustomYellow ctermbg=205 guibg=yellow guifg=black ctermfg=black
call matchadd('CustomYellow', '\<TODO\>')
hi CustomCyan ctermbg=205 guibg=Cyan guifg=black ctermfg=black
call matchadd('CustomCyan', '\<DEBUG\>')
hi CustomGray ctermbg=205 guibg=Gray guifg=black ctermfg=black
call matchadd('CustomGray', '\<TEMP\>')
```

The highlight works properly when I open different files in different Vim windows but, if I open different file in the same Vim window using tabs, the highlight stops working.

Comment: `matchadd()` only works for the current window, so if you want them to apply to several windows, you need to re-do it.

Comment: Is there any way to re-do it automatically?

Comment: throw it into a (Buf)WinEnter autocommand possibly or make a plugin out of it

Comment: May you give me an example according to the code I have posted please?

Answer (score 2):

`matchadd()`, like `:match`, only applies to the *current* window. A `:split` and also `:tab split` creates a new window, and that won't have the match highlighting. You need to re-do your match definitions for each new window.

`:autocmd WinEnter` lets you execute code whenever a window is entered. To avoid that additional identical matches are defined when a window is revisited, you could use a static `{id}` and suppress the error when that already exists with `:silent!`:

```
autocmd WinEnter * silent! call matchadd('CustomYellow', '\<TODO\>', 10, 12345)
```